# Can't install Google Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, 16.04, google-chrome, google

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 off a USB stick. I have tried to install Chrome via the Software Center and it says installing and then goes back to "install" a second later.

I have also tried via Terminal and have failed. I am fairly new to Ubuntu, but not Linux as a whole.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: Do you have a .deb file for Chrome downloaded from google's website ? If so, you can install it with `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file.deb` in the terminal.

Comment: I tried, says there is no such file or directory.

Answer (score 3):

It is better to use terminal. Download googlechrome.deb from there  website

Open terminal and `cd` to the installation directory
Then type:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
sudo gdebi google*
```

Now the browser should be installed and working normally

Comment: I executed the instructions as you stated above and I see in my opt/google/chrome the program but I cannot execute anything to get the google chrome browser to come up.  It does not show up in the dashboard of my Ubuntu 16.04 unity interface.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: simply do reboot, do give feedback

Comment: It worked for me without need for reboot.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with Software in Ubuntu 16.04, that cant install debs from internet. 
You may install the old Software Center, that still work fine and can manage downloaded debs: sudo apt-get install software-center. Then open the deb file with Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Even with old software center there are problems related to unmet dependencies. Terminal approach is best according to me.

Comment: I also can't install any updates. Seems like there is some kind of problem,

Answer (score 0):

You can install using the Synaptic Package Manager. Search in the All category for google-chrome-stable. Mark it for install, select to install any additional packages. Then select Apply. If the latest isn't installed, select to update the package. There was a recent update to package earlier today.

Comment: I think google repository is needed to be added to /etc/apt/sources.list.d in order for that to happen as google chrome is not there in the official repository. Chromium browser is present though.